# Why move constructor is called instead of copy constructor

Tags: c++, c++11

I'm trying to understand a move constructor,

usually a copy constructor is called when objects are copied

that what happen when I do not provide a move constructor,

but when I add a move constructor it is called instead of my copy constructor,

here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

struct A
{
    A()
    {
        cout << "A's constructor" << endl;
    }

    A(const A& rhs)
    {
        cout << "A's copy constructor" << endl;
    }

    A(A&& rhs)
    {
        cout << "A's move constructor" << endl;
    }
};

int main() {

    vector<A> v;

    cout << "==> push_back A():";
    v.push_back(A());

    cout << "==> push_back A():" << endl;
    v.push_back(A());

    return 0;
}
```

does the compiler try to optimize my code and choose the better method ?

Comment: Think about the name "**move** constructor", and take a look at your implementation of it. It takes the argument as a *constant* rvalue reference. How do you *move* from a *constant* value?

Comment: ok, so we cant move from const rvalue reference, I have updated the code.

Comment: @linuxD Did you mean to remove `const` from the copy constructor in the previous edit?

Comment: I removed the const qualifier yes

Comment: @linuxD The point of my comment was to draw your attention toward _a likely mistake_. The idiomatic signature of the copy constructor takes a `const` reference (i.e., you should have only removed `const` from the move constructor).

Comment: I updated the question. ok

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Basically, yes.

However, this is not about compiler optimisations as much as it is about how the language itself has been optimised.

Half of the point of move semantics is to allow efficient use of temporaries. That's why temporaries bind to rvalue refs and it's how the entire move semantics thing works. When you don't have a temporary but you wish to move something anyway, you write `std::move` to obtain an rvalue and trigger this same behaviour.

There is no point copying those temporaries when they are about to be destroyed anyway.

In concert with copy/move elision, this feature will result in much less redundant computing.

Note, however, that your move constructor is not terribly useful — if you ever wanted to make it actually do something (like, um, *move* stuff) you'd have to remove that `const`.

Answer (score 2):

rvalue references are better candidates to bind temporaries than const lvalue references. It is not about **optimizing** (as in compiler optimizations), it is about following standard. The actual optimization would be to not call copy constructor at all.